# Error passing variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have been spending hours(searching and trying) in every simple Mysql query. I am trying to pass a variable from one select statement to next statement. But i have been thrown an empty rows.

```
SET @id :='SELECT MAX(sId) from surveys';
SELECT typeId as type from surveys WHERE sId=@id;
PREPARE stmt from @id;
execute stmt;
```

I tried executing `SELECT MAX(sId) from surveys` which gives result as desired. But it seems that `@id` does not accept the values. Is there any error or any other suggestion to the solve this out?

Answer (score 0):

TRY this :

```
SET @s = 'SELECT typeId as type from surveys WHERE sId=?';
PREPARE stmt from @s;
SET @id = (SELECT MAX(sId) from surveys);
EXECUTE stmt USING @id;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: This still results in empty result set. I am working in phymyadmin SQL field directly and use Delimiter ; . is it making any difference with the output?